# Sentence Case for Textbox Issue

Tags: vb.net

So the code below basically converts whatever is in textbox to a sentence format. Although, it doesnt capitalize the letter "I"s, any help with this? Thanks

```
Public Shared Function SentenceCase(ByVal Input As String) As String
        Dim SentenceBreakers As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(".!?" & vbCrLf)
        Dim Pattern As String = "((?<=^[^" & SentenceBreakers & "\w]{0,})[a-z]|(?<![" & SentenceBreakers & "])(?<=[" & SentenceBreakers & "][^" & SentenceBreakers & "\w]{0,})[a-z])"
        Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Input, Pattern, Function(m) m.Value(0).ToString().ToUpper() & m.Value.Substring(1))
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding one more .Replace(" i "," I ") at the end

```
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Input, Pattern, Function(m) m.Value(0).ToString().ToUpper() & m.Value.Substring(1)).Replace(" i "," I ")
```